# Rails app slower on a new Dell with Ubuntu than on an old Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, ubuntu

I've been working in a client project using a MacBook Pro for two years now.
The project is a Rails 2.1.2 app that we are upgrading, and has a lot of unit/functional/integration/cucumber tests.
The complete test suite runs slower on a new Dell manchine than on the old Mac. Is that normal?

The specs for the Mac are:

- 2008 MacBook Pro, Lion 10.7.2.
- 8GB RAM, 2.53Ghz Core2Duo, 250HD.

The specs for the Dell are:

- New Dell XPS 15 (new model that came out this year).
- 8GB RAM, IntelCore™ i7-3632QM, 720HD.
- It has UBUNTU 12.10 64bit.

I  installed Ruby ree with RVM on both laptops.
They have the same gems versions managed with bundler.

The Mac tests times:

```
unit

real  9m23.025s
user  3m42.044s
sys 1m40.441s

cucumber

real  13m3.981s
user  8m46.322s
sys 1m24.287s
```

The Dell tests times:

```
unit

real 35m4.003s
user 2m52.155s
sys  0m58.388s

cucumber

real 28m54.349s
user 6m32.773s
sys  0m44.751s
```

The Dell times are slow. Is there something I'm missing? Is this normal? Could it be ree? Ubuntu?

Comment: Try RVM-installed 1.9.3.

Comment: The hard drive is important too, and will usually slow down Rails apps more than anything else.

Comment: If anyone is having the same problem (as I did) I recommend doing the steps here 
http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2009/06/04/mount-options-to-improve-ext4-file-system-performance/

Seem like is a problem of ext4 partitions. I was having the same issue and the link solve the problem.

Comment: These are the times now:
unit
real 6m12.411s
user 2m46.254s
sys 0m56.432s

cucumber
real 7m53.705s
user 5m41.813s
sys 0m37.422s

Thanks to the people who reply

Answer (score 2):

The real number is higher, but sys/user are lower. That means either the dell is busier with other processes or it's spending more time waiting on I/O.

Comment: +Mark Thomas this is a rails 2.1.2 app, so I have to use ree

Comment: +pguardiario How can I know wich if the two is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the backing database for your application configured the same way? It's possible you're using a terrible stock configuration on Ubuntu that's causing your tests to absolutely drag.

It might even be the case the tests are waiting around for a network resource that isn't available, or one that accepts connections really slowly because of misconfigured DNS or something like that.

Ruby 1.9.3 should be a lot faster than ree-1.8.7 because of a [require bug](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-faster-loading-times-require-4927.html) that was fixed. It could be that the Ubuntu build of that Ruby suffers a lot more when loading dependencies that could be slowing down your tests.

A better way to test Ruby speed is to see how long Rails 2.x `script/console` takes to spin up. This wouldn't hit the database so you can test Ruby in isolation.

Comment: script/console is faster on ubuntu that on mac

Comment: Have you benchmarked your database? `log/test.log` will contain a break-down of query times so you can compare that to your reference system.